# Behavior of Optional Class in Java8

Tags: java, java-8

What is the Optional class in java 8? What its significance? Can the object of optional class  hold null value?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: i had seen it but i didn't understand

Comment: The usage of `Optional<T>` to test against a `null` value is unnecessarily verbose, if only one or two objects are to be tested against a `null` value.

Comment: Why did you downvote this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is container to avoid null pointer exception.
It is an implementation of NULL object pattern. Here is an article on it
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: i am not able to understand this from above link

Answer (score 0):

It's simply to handle null better. 
for example -:

```
if(book.getAuthor()==null)
   //do something
else
   System.out.println(book.getAuthor().getName())
```

can be better handled through optional as -:

```
System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(book.getAuthor()).orElse(/**return something else instead**/).getName())
```

from the doc ->

Optional.ofNullable(T value)

> Returns an Optional describing the specified value, if non-null, otherwise returns an empty Optional.

and orElse(T other)

> Return the value if present, otherwise return other.